# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ belong to a field of order $8$ and that $a^2 + ab + b^2 =0$ then $a=0$ and $b=0$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ belong to a field of order $8$ and $a^2 + ab + b^2 =0$. Then $a=0$ and $b=0$. Do the same when the field has order $2^n$ with $n$ odd?

If one of the term is zero, i.e. let $b=0$ then $a^2 =0 \implies a =0$. We also note that since field is of order $8$, $a^7 = 1 = b^7$.

But how to bring a contradiction if I consider any one to be not equal to $0$? I want to use only basics.

Comment: I have thought of a solution can I post it in the answer?

Comment: Yes. You could post your solution as an answer yoursefl. However, I'm sure this question is a duplicate. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 4):

First we have

$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=a^3-b^3=0$, or $a^3=b^3$.

Since $a^7=b^7=1,$

$a^7=a^4a^3=a^4b^3=1$, $b^7=b^3b^4=a^3b^4=1$, and $a^4b^3=a^3b^4$.

So $a^3b^3(a-b)=0$.

If $a^3=0$, then $a=0$, and then $b^2=0$, so $b=0$. Similarly it is true for $b^3=0$.

Finally, if $a^3\neq0$ and $b^3\neq0$, then $a=b$. So there is $3a^2=0$, and thus

$a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: $a^3=b^3\Rightarrow a^9=b^9\Rightarrow a^2=b^2$. The advantage is that this argument can be adapted for proving the general case since $3\mid 2^n+1$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 3):

If one of them, say $b$, is not $0$, then $\frac{a}{b}$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, which lies in a (the) degree-$2$ extension of $\mathbb F_2$, and therefore it does not lie in the degree-$3$ extension of order $8$. Same is true for any odd $n$ and for the same reason.